# Python Pandas read_csv UnicodeDecodeError: 'uff-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a txt file with data as below.

```
"Name","Email","Active","IsGroup"
"David","david@gmail.com",1,1
"John","John@gmail.com",0,1
"Steff","steff@gmail.com",1,0
```

I would like to get the data frame as below.

```
Name      Email          Active     IsGroup
David  david@gmail.com     1           1 
John   john@gmail.com      0           1
Steff  steff@gmail.com     1           0
```

I tried to do as below. But it didn't work. How can I get this as above?

`users = pd.read_csv('file.txt', delimiter=",").replace('"', '', regex=True)`

Error:

> Python Pandas read_csv UnicodeDecodeError: 'uff-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: It sounds like maybe you're trying to read a file that has a [BOM](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the front of it.  The text data you show isn't the whole story, as that text doesn't start with a `0xff` character.  You should be able to use a text editor to save your input file as plain text with no BOM at the front of it.  Once you're past this first problem, do some Googling.  I expect that there are many sources of information on the net on how to read a CSV file into Pandas.  Or maybe it will just work as you've got it now.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it seems better just to ignore the encoding error through

> encoding_errors: str, optional, default “strict”

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=read_csv#pandas.read_csv

https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers

```
users = pd.read_csv(file.txt, encoding_errors="ignore")
```